# how to download and modify a complete webpage?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I would like to download the wikipedia page for the funniest joke in the world https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World%27s_funniest_joke

Then, I would like to replace all the occurrences of the word `joke` with the word `apple` (yes, it is funnier indeed).

The key point is that I would like to be able to click on the output `html` file (with apples instead of jokes) and be able to see the same images, css, and output as the original webpage in my browser.

- I tried to download the `mhtml` file with chrome and modify the file using `f.read()` but the file looks like binary data.
- Using `requests` and `beautifulsoup` via `(BeautifulSoup(requests.get(myurl), 'html.parser'))` only gives me raw `html` without the formatting.

What can I do? I do not mind some manual steps (say, download the files somewhere first).

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need a basic course or two in modern web design.

Comment: thank you this is a useful comment. do you have a possible solution maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the Wikipedia page as `mhtml` and was able to replace every instance of the word `joke`(s) with `apple`(s). Here's the code I used to replace the target strings.

```
#! python
import os
import sys
import fileinput

# Read in the file
with open("World's funniest joke - Wikipedia.mhtml", 'r') as file :
  filedata = file.read()

# Replace the target string
filedata = filedata.replace('joke', 'apple')
filedata = filedata.replace('jokes', 'apples')
filedata = filedata.replace('Joke', 'Apple')
filedata = filedata.replace('Jokes', 'Apples')

# Write the file out again
with open("World's funniest joke - Wikipedia.mhtml", 'w') as file:
  file.write(filedata)
```

edit:
Added Mad Physicist's suggestion, will replace all instances of jokes to apples.

[image: Proof of work, with edits fully working and comprehensively replacing all string variants of the word "joke"]

Thanks!

Comment: thanks! when you open the modified mhtml file do you still see the same formatting as the original page (color, etc?)

Comment: You aren't replacing `Joke` and `Jokes` (capital `J`)

Comment: Yes, you do still see the words as blue or hyperlinked. If you click the blue text  after "edit:" in my response you will see what it looks like after you run the code for a short while on the file.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thank you! You are 100% right. I have added that to my code, per your suggestion. Should work great now.

Comment: Perhaps (a) update the picture, and (b) verify that you did not replace any of the link targets

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @Mad Physicist. I've updated the picture to verify that the code demonstrated in my answer will replace __all__ instances. I appreciate the feedback! :)

Comment: maybe just one refinement: would it be possible to use regex instead of `.replace()`

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ It's not entirely trivial because the replacement depends on the capture.

Comment: [link](https://prnt.sc/1rc522j)

Try to use `re.sub`